# In java.awt.CardLayout, why are first(container) and next(container) not static methods?

Tags: java

Today I study java knowledge about awt(GUI programming). When I read about the `CardLayOut` method `void first(parent)`, I noticed that it is not static method.

The method is used like this:

```java
Panel p=new Panel();
p.setLayout(new CardLayout());
p.add(new Button())
p.add
....
CardLayout.first(p)
```

Since I use an anonymous class, I cannot use a object method.   I thought that the `first` method doesn't actually use `this`，but apparently I was wrong.

Why can't `first`, `next` and so on be `static` methods?

Answer (score 0):

You need to save a reference to the new CardLayout object you create, and then make the call on *that* object.

```
CardLayout cl = new CardLayout()
p.setLayout(cl);

...

cl.first(p)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer,but I want to know that why need a object to call this method, and this method is not relative with this object I create,beause this method only to change Visibility of components in p(parameter:Panel)

Comment: Because the CardLayout _object_ is the one responsible for the layout, not the CardLayout _class_. A static "first" method would have to extract the CardLayout object from the Panel object, and then there would need to be _another_ "first" method that the class calls on the instance. It becomes clunky and impractical. Better to just force you — the programmer — to keep a reference that instance and then make that call yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If we look at the code for `first`, `next`, `previous` and `last` in `CardLayout` it is true that the current implementation of methods only manipulating state in the `parent` component.

However:

1. The methods do check that the supplied `parent` is the correct parent for this `CardLayout`.  They can only do this if the methods are not static.  This check is arguably a good thing.  Accidentally using the wrong `parent` would be a source of confusing and incorrect behavior.
2. The above is just the current implementation.  Past or future versions might conceivably have more significant dependencies on the state of `this`.
3. Polymorphism.  If the methods were static, then it would not be able to create a custom subclass that *overrides* these methods.
4. Instance methods are more "object oriented".

These are all small reasons.  But they are all reasons ... and AFAIK there are no reasons (at all) that the methods *should* be `static`.

But maybe a better question is why is the `parent` parameter required at all.  (I don't know the answer to that ...)

But the bottom line is that this part part of the AWT API has been designed like this, and there is no chance that it will be changed.

---

Apparently, you are having difficulties with using `first` in an anonymous inner class.

The problem is not due to the method being an instance methods.  (Instance methods can be called in anonymous classes.)  The problem is more likely:

- that you don't have a reference to the `CardLayout` instance in a variable which is in scope, or
- that the variable is a local variable that is not `final` or effectively final.

Both of those problems have easy fixes.